# How to get the delivery polygon for a given address/latlong?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

Say, I have a restaurant at address "Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA".  I also have the lat/long for this address.  My delivery radius is 4 miles.  How to get the polygon around this address and store it my database using google maps?

I'd like to show the delivery polygon in my website and also if a customer enters a delivery address, how do I check if the entered address falls within the polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick/cheap way to do this is to calculate a rectangular bounding box (vs. circle), and store the NW/SE corners of the bounding box for the location. Then check if the Lat/Lng of the new address is within the bounding box of the other location. Here's some pseudo code:

```
// location is an object that has bounding box and location information (e.g., address)
// bounding box is represented as two points: NW and SE corner


foreach location in locations do            
{
     boundingbox = location.boundingbox;  
     NW = boundingbox.NW;
     SE = boundingbox.SE;
     if ( ( Lat <= NW.Lat && lat >= SE.Lat ) &&
        ( Lon >= NW.Lon && Lon <= SE.Lon ) )box

     {
         // The lat/lng of the new address is within the bounding box of this location     
     } 
}
```

Here's a quick/approx. formulae (pseudo code) for calculating a bounding box of a location where the sides are 10 miles from the center (where Lat/Lon are the center of the location):

```
NW.Lat = Lat - 0.145;
SE.Lat = Lat + 0.145;
rLat   = Lat * 0.0174532925; // radians
coff   = Math.cos(rlat); // approximating curvature of longitude lines
NW.Lon = Lon + (0.145 * coff);
SE.Lon = Lon - (0.145 * coff);
```

Comment: How did you get 0.14?

Comment: Are there any API's available to compute the boundaries given the center?  Reason I'm asking is, based on weather conditions, I will have to update the delivery radius frequently.  Example: if it's snowing the delivery radius could be set to 1 mile.  So, just wanted to know if these can be calculated using an API call.

Comment: First, I changed it to 0.145 to make it more exact. This is the how much degree difference in latitude equals 10 miles. 1 degree latitude is 69 miles (hence 10 / 69). If you want 1 mile difference change the number to 0.0145. For longitude, it starts at 69 miles per degree at the equator and then narrows towards the poles. The COS() equation approximates the curvature.